# Add Customer Payment tree in Cash Register In Openerp

Tags: openerp-7

How to add customer payment tree to cahs register of openerp.I add in my coding like that.

'customer_payment_lines':fields.one2many('account.voucher','account_id','Customer Payments'),
 in account.bank.statement.

But I can't see any line of customer payment in cash register.
What should i do?
Somebody help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For one2many, It is neccesary to put many2one in other object. in your case, you have to put many2one in account.voucher. and also check that you have kept your field "customer_payment_lines" in view. Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<openerp>
  <data>
      <!-- product tree -->
    <record id="view_royalfood_customer_payment" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">Royal Food Customer Payment</field> 
      <field name="model">account.bank.statement</field> 
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_bank_statement_form2" />
      <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
        <field name="opening_details_ids" position="after"> 
                <field name="customer_payment_lines">
                    <tree>
                         <field name="name"/>
                         <field name="company_id"/>
                         <field name="account_id"/>
                     </tree>
                 </field>
        </field>
      </field> 
   </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: yes.i also use many2one but that is not working.Can't show data of account voucher.

Comment: show your code. so that i can help you. py and xml file both.

Comment: in xml...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
 <data>
  <!-- product tree -->
  <record id="view_royalfood_customer_payment" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">Royal Food Customer Payment</field>
   <field name="model">account.bank.statement</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_bank_statement_form2" />
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="line_ids" context="{'date':date}" position="after">
     <field name="customer_payment_lines" />
    </field>
   </field>
  </record>
 </data>
</openerp>

Comment: class test(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "account.bank.statement"
    _description = "Cash Book Accounting"

    _columns = {
                'customer_payment_lines':fields.many2one('account.voucher', 'Voucher', required=1, ondelete='cascade'),
                }
royalfood_cash_book()

Comment: No .It is get total of account.voucher.I want to get account.voucher tree in account.bank.statement.

Comment: @my updated answer. try this. in tree view you can show as many fields you want of account.voucher